# Recyclerview does not update while adding data in Sqlite from service class?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here i am trying to save data in sqlite database from firebase database and its saved successfully.And Sqlite databse updated regullarly when new data added.
But the problem is that new data only appear when activity is restarted.
Recyclerview is not update until get  back to activity. 
Here is my service class.

```
      public class NetworkBroadcast  extends Service
    {
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            checkNewMessage(mAuth);
        }
private void checkNewMessage(final FirebaseAuth mAuth)
    {
        final String CurrentUID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        final DatabaseReference MessageRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(CurrentUID);
        final DatabaseReference MessageSenderRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages");
        MessageRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
            {

                final String SenderKey=dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Log.i("SERVER_MESSAGE",SenderKey);
                final MyDbHandler myDbHandler=new MyDbHandler(NetworkBroadcast.this,SenderKey+".db",null,1);
                final MessagesAdapter messagesAdapter=new MessagesAdapter(myDbHandler.sqlMessagesList(),NetworkBroadcast.this,SenderKey,myDbHandler);
                MessageRef.child(SenderKey).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
                    {

                            Messages messages=dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                            String pushKey=dataSnapshot.getKey();
                            checkDatabaseHasMessageOrNotWithStatus(messages,pushKey,messagesAdapter,myDbHandler);
                            checkMessageStatus(messages,CurrentUID,SenderKey,myDbHandler);
                            chnageSenderMessageStatus(messages,CurrentUID,MessageSenderRef);
                        messagesAdapter.updateData(myDbHandler.sqlMessagesList());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
                    {

                        Messages statusmessage=dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        String key=dataSnapshot.getKey();

                        boolean update=myDbHandler.upDateDataBaseForStatus(statusmessage.getStatus(),key);
                        if (update=true)
                        {
                            Log.i("SERVER_MESSAGE","my message is update");
                        }

                    }

                });
            }

        });
    }
    }
```

and Adapter class constructor is

```
public MessagesAdapter(List<SqlMessages> userMessagesList, Context mContext, String messageReceiverId, MyDbHandler myDbHandler)
    {
        this.userMessagesList = userMessagesList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        ReceiverID=messageReceiverId;
        this. myDbHandler=myDbHandler;

    } 
public void updateData(List<SqlMessages> sqlMessages)
    {
        this.userMessagesList=sqlMessages;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: use an interface to trigger a method that calls adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() put a check if the activity currently exists by this.isfinishing()

Comment: please add an answer box

Comment: i also tried updatedata method in onchildAdded.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to define your Activity, something like this code. pay attention to the way that this code updates its adapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MessagesAdapter adapter;
    Recyclerview recycler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    List<SqlMessages> list=new ArrayList();
    adapter=new MessagesAdapter(list);
    recycler=findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LayoutManager());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final List<SqlMessages> list=data.getSomeData();
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.updateData(list);
        }
    });
}
}
```

You should rewrite your Adapter to look like this code. remember notifyDataSetChanged must be called from UiThread.

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolderClass> {
List<SqlMessages> userMessagesList;
Context mContext;
MyDbHandler  myDbHandler;
String ReceiverID;

public MessagesAdapter(List<SqlMessages> userMessagesList, Context mContext, String messageReceiverId, MyDbHandler myDbHandler){
    this.userMessagesList = userMessagesList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    ReceiverID=messageReceiverId;
    this. myDbHandler=myDbHandler;
}

@Override
public YourViewHolderClass onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(someLayout, parent, false);
    return new YourViewHolderClass(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final YourViewHolderClass holder, int position) {
    holder.setSomething(userMessagesList.get(position).getSomething());
    holder.setAnotherThing(userMessagesList.get(position).getAnotherThing())
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void updateData(List<SqlMessages> sqlMessages){
    this.userMessagesList=sqlMessages;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

And YourViewHolderClass looks like this

```
public class YourViewHolderClass  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView textView;
TextView textView1;

public YourViewHolderClass(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
}

public void setSomething(String x) {
    this.textView.setText(x);
}
public void setAnotherthing(String x) {
    this.textView1.setText(x);
}
}
```

in someLayout you must define a CardView item. something like code below

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardViewxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Where you write uithread in your answer ? And cardview is compulsory for inflate layout ?

Comment: I've updated my codes. And now you can see how we call updateData() from the UiThread.